# Почему зависает код?

Tags: javascript

```
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


for(let xer = 0; xer<num.length; xer++){
  num.splice(xer,0, 'какой-то текст')
}
```

По идее же, после каждого элемента должен вставиться текст, но код зависает будто цикл бесконечный

Comment: На каждой итерации цикла количество элементов в массиве увеличивается на единицу.

Comment: ну так он и должен выдать мне массив из 20 элементов а не зависать

Comment: Вы прописале в цикле условие не на 20 элементов, а на длину массива. Так как длина массива постоянно увеличивается — цикл становится бесконечным. Значение `xer` никогда не сможет стать больше чем `num.length`, потому что `num.length` постоянно увеличивается.

Comment: да, точно, теперь понял) спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой эффект хотели?

```js
let num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


for(let xer = num.length - 1 ; xer >= 0 ; xer-- ){
  num.splice(xer, 0, 'какой-то текст');
}

console.log(num);
```

По идее итерировать массив и при этом добавлять или удалять элементы правильнее в обратном порядке вернее чтобы индексы исходного массива ссылались на один и тот же  элемент до и после изменения массива

Comment: @wololo спс за замечания

Comment: спасибо больше, учту

Answer (score 3):

```
for (let xer = 0; xer<num.length; xer += 2) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем `num.splice` вы вставляете в массив новый элемент, этим увеличивая длину массива на 1. И это у вас происходит при каждой итерации цикла. Поэтому и получается бесконечный цикл